# How do I set the width of a table cell (<td>) up to X% but no more than Ypx

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I would like to have a table with two columns.

I know how to set the width of a column as percentage of the table width or by pixel count.

I would like the left column to have the maximum width, while I need the right column to be 20% of the width of the table, but no more than 150px.

The thing is that the table width is dependent of client screen resolution, but the right column should never grow "too much".

How do I do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636269/table-td-width-under-control

Comment: Thanks, but this is not it. I need a relative width with a maximum boundary. I'm families with max-width, but this doesn't help, because when user width along with max-width, the max-width has no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Look into css properties `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: I'm families with max-width, but this doesn't help, because when user width along with max-width, the max-width has no affect. Can you be more specific?