# Fix the width and height of the table td

Tags: html, css, extjs, cross-browser, extjs4.1

In my project, I am trying to [fix the width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636290/1577396) of `td`'s by doing the following:

```
td{
   max-width:100px;
   max-height:100px;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   overflow:hidden;
   word-wrap:break-word;  /* CSS3 */
}
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/avifoj/1/edit)

But as you can see in the fiddle, the td is increasing in height if the content in it is increasing.

Anyway to fix it?

Please give a solution which is `cross-browser`.

If there is a fix available in extjs then that could also help me.

PS: I know [using div's](http://jsbin.com/awohum/1/edit) it can be achieved easily but now I can't change it.

Comment: try [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksB2K/), this might help you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will delete my answer after I'm removed from ban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your content with div

```
table{width:500px;height:200px;}

td{border:1px solid green; width:100px;
  height:100px;}
/* My fix try */


td div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-wrap:break-word; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pgrKM/1/)**

Comment: +1 Yes this is working. Is there any way to fix it if I don't know the width and height of the td's? (In real project, I just stretched the table by giving `width:100%; height:100%` and nothing more)

Comment: atleast height should be known right?? otherwise why do u even want to stop the content from flowing

Answer (score 0):

My problem was somewhat different. I was only giving `width:100%` and `height:100%` to the `table` tag. i.e, no fixed `td`'s.

I solved this by adding `div`'s inside each `td` tag and giving them fixed dimensions.

```
td>div{
   /* Giving values less than the td values by assuming */
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is the [**Working  Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/avifoj/3/edit)

Thanks to @Sowmya to give this idea. :)

PS: *I am posting this as an answer so that it could help others in future*.