# How to reduce the width of the td when text is too much big

Tags: html, css, jsf

I am working on an application where I am using a dropdown which is populated by large values. The values destroy the page structure. How can I adjust the dropdown length to correctly show the page? This is the code for the dropdown:

```
 <td>
     <h:selectOneMenu id="basicSalary" value="#{searchMemberBean.memberBO.grossSalaryRange}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="SELECT" itemValue=" " id = "selectItem11"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Salary less than 4,000 AED per month" itemValue="1" id = "selectItem12"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Salary between 4,001 and 12,000 AED per month" itemValue="2" id = "selectItem33"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Salary greater than 12,000 AED per month" itemValue="3" id = "selectItem34"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="No salary-for dependents or children that do not acquire a salary" itemValue="4" id = "selectItem35"/>
     </h:selectOneMenu>
</td>
```

How can I adjust the dropdown length to fit the page?

Comment: JSF is in this regard just an html generator ((c) BalusC). Look at the client side html. Ask a question about that code and than apply it to your jsf code.

Comment: can you provide the complete dropdown code??

Answer (score -2):

Did you try max-width or max-height?

Comment: where i should use that ? can you edit my code please??

Comment: You can write inline CSS like style="max-width:100px"

or you can just add it to your outlined css like
.your_class { max-width:100px; }

and add the class to your items with class="your_class"

Comment: i used <td style="max-width: 150px;word-wrap: break-word;"> did not worked

Comment: give your td a classname and outline the css.

td.yourclass {

max-width: 150px;word-wrap: break-word;

}

Comment: It was answered here before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636269/prevent-text-from-overlap-table-td-width